# AngularJS input $valid is always false with no error

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, frontend

I'm trying to apply an AngularJs validation in my project. So the following code was written:

```
 <form name="recipeTitle">
   <input ng-if="edit" required type="text" ng-model="recipe.name" name="name"/>
 </form>
 <span>valid = {ng recipeTitle.name.$valid ng}</span>
 <span>errors = {ng recipeTitle.name.$error ng}</span>
```

If no value was entered in input, that returns:

```
valid = false
errors = {"required":true}
```

When any value appears in input field, validation returns:

```
valid = false 
errors = {}
```

And I have no idea, how to make a $valid property become true. Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: If you will provide a plunker link for example it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WQZmtdYf7GAyMWjbQh1P?p=preview). But plunker code with minimum necessary changes works as expected)

Comment: If nothing else works, you could manually set valid to true via JavaScript if 'errors' is empty and false otherwise, every time the input is changed

Comment: @Kamil code in plunker works perfectly.

Comment: @Rebornix yep, it does. And I have no idea what i have done wrong in my app.

Comment: Your example works as expected - http://plnkr.co/edit/brzEMlzOF9jtoWYsl9mL?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. It works if you use the $scope:

```
<span>valid = {ng $scope.recipeTitle.name.$valid ng}</span>
<span>errors = {ng $scope.recipeTitle.name.$error ng}</span>
```

instead of

```
<span>valid = {ng recipeTitle.name.$valid ng}</span>
<span>errors = {ng recipeTitle.name.$error ng}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not check it right now, couse we've already made a workaround, but I'l check it in order to help smb.)